# Watch window.scrollY and router :id in Vue2JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, resize, addeventlistener, watch

So basically I was able to watch `window.scrollY` by adding normal eventListner of resize in created hook and remove it in destroyed hook. On resize I was checking `window.scrollY` and if it was upper or lower than 500  I was changing boolean variable on which I bind different classes:

```
<nav class="navbar u-no-padding"
     v-if="displayedNav"
     :class="minimizedNav ? 'navbar__not-collapsed' : 'navbar__collapsed'">
```

Also if in url I have `:id` (which is part of vue router) then I'm totaly hiding nav so I also use `v-if` directive.

It was working fine but then I realize that I can use vue `watch` to watch `window.srollY` in order to change some boolean variable in data() when `window.srollY` is upper or lower than 500

I can also watch `this.$route.params.id` and if it's set then change `this.displayed` to false.

So in the end I will have two watchers which will change booleans and on this booleans I'm doing something with nav as shown in html. I tried to create that and end up with

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            minimizedNav: true,
            displayedNav: true,
            buildingId: this.$route.params.id
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'buildingId' : (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if(data) this.displayedNav = false;
        },
        'window.scrollY' : (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if(data > 500) this.minimizedNav = false;
            if(data <= 500) this.minimizedNav = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I was suspecting that it will `console.log(data)` where data is `this.$route.params.id` or `buildingId` on every its change. But it doesn't console anything. Why, what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue attaches watchers to all your data properties inside the component (the state), which also keep track of where it is used.

Vue doesn't attach a watcher to `window` variables. It only does that for its data, and computed properties. Due to this reason, your `window.scrollY` watcher is never called.

Your previous solution was correct when you were listening for the change on resize.

Comment: So I can't have it done with watch? What about buildingId as it also doesn't work.

Comment: @BT101 you can refer to [`vue-scroll` directive](https://github.com/wangpin34/vue-scroll/tree/2.0-compatible/src) then implement your own one. @NishantArora Vue watcher can also track computed property.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `watch` you can use `computed` to return your conditions directly like this

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {}
    },

    computed: {
        displayedNav: function() {
            if(this.$route.params.id){
               return false;
            else {
               return true;
            }
        },
        minimizedNav: function() => {
            if(window.scrollY > 500) {
              return false;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your template use the computed property like this.

```
<nav class="navbar u-no-padding"
     v-if="displayedNav"
     :class="minimizedNav ? 'navbar__not-collapsed' : 'navbar__collapsed'">
```

Vuejs advices to use computed over watch wherever possible

> When you have some data that needs to change based on some other data,
> it is tempting to overuse `watch` - especially if you are coming from an
> AngularJS background. However, it is often a better idea to use a
> `computed` property rather than an imperative `watch` callback

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Comment: This works for `displayedNav` but doesn't for `minimizedNav`

Comment: I think computed also can't handle window object